# iOS : Scroll on tableview

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

i've a stupid problem with a tableview (with static cell.)

When i use my app' on a  iPhone 4, to show all the content, i need to scroll. The problem is, the scroll is too small, because when i want to show the content at the bottom, i need to "stay" on the scroll to see it... and of course it's a problem.

How to adjust the scroll of this tableview ? (i didn't set a scrollview, it's just the basic scroll)

It's hard to explain...

If someone knows..

EDIT : this is my view : (i have 3 cell below "Prototype cells")

[image]

Comment: I understand a little bit, can you show how do you create your table view? (frame)

Comment: just increase your table view's height to 100 more

Comment: What do you want to see ? i didn't understand^^